# What are the risks of using a penile stretcher?

Tags: penis

What are the risks of using those devices? And how can you prevent risks and problems, or recognize them before its too late? I'm seriously considering buying one of those, and using it for about 10 hours daily for approximately 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

Risks appear to be low, if they are used as intended.

> There were no adverse events including skin changes, ulcerations, hypoesthesia or diminished rigidity.

[Penile Traction Therapy for Treatment of Peyronie's Disease: A Single-Center Pilot Study](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1743-6109.2008.00814.x/abstract)

> The application of such devices can be recommended in all patients regardless of the penile length, because of the low risk of complications

[Non-invasive methods of penile lengthening: fact or fiction?](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1464-410X.2010.09647.x/full)

However, all studies on this I found had a really small sample size. So rare risks could just not have appeared.

Comment: "..all studies...had a really small sample size" lol